# Выравнивание заголовка в Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, toolbar

В `Activity` используется метод `setTitle()` для установки заголовка. Но заголовок устанавливается прижатый к левому краю. Как можно сделать выравнивание заголовка по центру `toolbar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код в вашу  xml разметку:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hint: а гамбургер и options меню не помешают центрированию? Не говоря уже про поиск...